# Pass array variables to next part of function

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am working with an integer array in my JavaScript function which I have simplified down to -

```
var recs = new Array();
recs[0] = 1;
recs[1] = 2;
recs[2] = 3;
```

Further down my function I am using each value of `recs`like -

```
data: [
        recs[0], recs[1], recs[2]
  ]
```

How can I iterate through each value in recs and add it to `data` without hardcoding them, as the number of values is likely to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you dont mind using the same array reference, you can simply do:

`data: recs`

Otherwise you can clone the array using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

`data: recs.slice()`

*Note: If you look at the function reference you will see that the same function allows you to slice off a specific portion of the array as well.*

Comment: is the zero is optional in here `recs.slice(0)`?

Comment: @ajax333221 Yes it is. "If begin is omitted, slice begins from index 0." - Taken from MDN

Comment: Strange that MDN doesn't show begin as optional in the function signature, but it is indeed optional: http://jsfiddle.net/k68Hu/1

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just need:

```
 var data = recs;
```

or

```
  ...
  data:recs
  ...
```

or if you want to keep a diff reference then:

```
data : [].concat(recs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop to iterate through the items in recs

```
var recs = []; // its better practice to use the array literal here instead of new Array()
recs[0] = 1;
recs[1] = 2;
recs[2] = 3;

var i = 0,
    count = recs.length,
    data = [];

for (; i < count; i++) {
  data[i] = recs[i];
}
```